# How to get access to trafficanalytics.here.com

Tags: here-api

I Would like to try **trafficanalytics.here.com** api. However I faced an issue with logging into this site. I think I need it to obtain customer key and customer secret. Is this API available for the freemium accounts?

Whenever I try to reach the **https://trafficanalytics.here.com** it points me to log in with HERE.com credentials. When I use my credentials from HERE.com, the application communicates me about "incorrect login / password". How can I login there?

Answer (score 0):

Traffic analytics is a premium content hence this is not available in freemium account.